# Узнать ID сегмента номенклатуры

Tags: 1с

Как в `1С 8.3` можно узнать `ID` Сегмента номенклатуры (`Справочники > Сегменты номенклатуры`)?

Answer (score 1):

Что вы подразумеваете под ID ?

Если уид в таблице sql то можете попробовать:

```
XMLСтрока(СсылкаСегментНоменклатуры)
```

Если ID - код, тогда

```
ОбщегоНазначения.ЗначениеРеквизитаОбъекта(СсылкаСегментНоменклатуры, "Код")
```

ИЛИ

```
СсылкаСегментНоменклатуры.Код
```